# Coq: goal variable not transformed by induction when appearing on left side of arrow

Tags: coq, induction

I am trying to prove the following theorem by induction over l. It's an easy theorem on paper, however when I try to prove it in Coq I am not getting the induction goal I would expect.

```
Theorem nodup_app__disjoint: forall {X: Type} (l: list X),
  (forall l1 l2 : list X, l = l1 ++ l2 -> Disjoint l1 l2) -> NoDup l.
Proof.
  intros X l. induction l.
  - intros F. apply nodup_nil.
  - (* ??? *)
```

The state at this point:

```
1 subgoal
X : Type
x : X
l : list X
IHl : (forall l1 l2 : list X, l = l1 ++ l2 -> Disjoint l1 l2) -> NoDup l
______________________________________(1/1)
(forall l1 l2 : list X, x :: l = l1 ++ l2 -> Disjoint l1 l2) ->
NoDup (x :: l)
```

But that is not at all the goal I would expect! Shouldn't `x :: l = l1 ++ l2` be replaced by `l = l1 ++ l2`?

Here are the propositions I'm working with, in case you'd like to reproduce the problem and see for yourself:

```
Inductive Disjoint {X : Type}: list X -> list X -> Prop :=
  | disjoint_nil: Disjoint [] []
  | disjoint_left: forall x l1 l2, Disjoint l1 l2 -> ~(In x l2) -> Disjoint (x :: l1) l2
  | disjoint_right: forall x l1 l2, Disjoint l1 l2 -> ~(In x l1) -> Disjoint l1 (x :: l2).

Inductive NoDup {X: Type}: list X -> Prop :=
  | nodup_nil: NoDup []
  | nodup_cons: forall hd tl, NoDup tl -> ~(In hd tl) -> NoDup (hd :: tl).
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your theorem. The `l` in `forall l1 l2, l = l1 ++ l2 -> Disjoint l1 l2` seems useless. The induction scheme seems ok to me: every instance bound by `l` will be replaced with `nil` or `x :: l`. Could you state the exact lemma your are trying to prove, maybe you translation in Coq is not correct ?

Comment: Also, you might be missing `NoDup l1` and `NoDup l2` in your lemma ? Just a wild guess ;)

Comment: @Vinz The premise says that for any "cut" of a list `l`, the "sections" (`l1` and `l2`) are disjoint. That implies `l` has no duplicates. If there were duplicates in `l` it would have form `l' ++ [x] ++ l'' ++ [x] ++ l'''` and this would get us a contradiction because `l1` = `l' ++ [x]` and `l2` = `l'' ++ [x] ++ l'''` are not disjoint.

Comment: Oh.. ok, I got it the wrong way. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But that is not at all the goal I would expect! Shouldn't `x :: l = l1 ++ l2` be replaced by `l = l1 ++ l2`?

**Short answer**: It should not!

#### Induction principle for lists

Let's recall the induction principle for lists:

```
Check list_ind.
(*
list_ind
  : forall (A : Type) (P : list A -> Prop),
    P [] ->
    (forall (a : A) (l : list A), P l -> P (a :: l)) ->
    forall l : list A, P l
*)
```

It means that in order to prove that a predicate `P` holds for all lists (`forall l : list A, P l`), one needs to prove that

- `P` holds for the empty list -- `P []`;
- `P` holds for all non-empty lists, given that it holds for their tails  -- `(forall (a : A) (l : list A), P l -> P (a :: l))`.

#### Applying the list induction principle to the goal

Now, we have the following goal:

```
(forall l1 l2, l = l1 ++ l2 -> Disjoint l1 l2) -> NoDup l.
```

To see what goals we should get when trying to prove the statement by induction on `l`, let's mechanically substitute `l` in the above with `[]` in one case and `h :: tl` the other.

`[]` case:

```
(forall l1 l2, [] = l1 ++ l2 -> Disjoint l1 l2) -> NoDup [].
```

`h :: tl` case:

```
(forall l1 l2, h :: tl = l1 ++ l2 -> Disjoint l1 l2) -> NoDup (h :: tl).
```

This is what you've got above (modulo the renaming). For the second case you are also getting the induction hypothesis, which we get from the original statement substituting `tl` for `l`:

```
(forall l1 l2, tl = l1 ++ l2 -> Disjoint l1 l2) -> NoDup tl.
```

---

Incidentally, the theorem is provable and you might find the following helper lemmas useful:

```
Lemma disjoint_cons_l {X} (h : X) l1 l2 :
  Disjoint (h :: l1) l2 -> Disjoint l1 l2.
Admitted.

Lemma disjoint_singleton {X} h (l : list X) :
  Disjoint [h] l -> ~ In h l.
Admitted.
```

Comment: I think you somehow managed to distill the problem's difficulty into those two lemmas, because I am completely blocked on both of them! Do I need any special trick? Induction on the various parameters leads me nowhere.

Comment: Here is the [full solution](https://gist.github.com/anton-trunov/f528daadf9977c43f9c37e3d0b68a152). Notice that I reuse the standard `NoDup`  predicate. You might need to use the `remember` tactic.